# Верстка под safari

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как проверить сайт в safari если ты на винде?

Comment: запустить сафари и зайти на сайт :-)

Comment: винда такая хрупкая сломается ведь, может нужно слезть с нее и включить комп для начала?

Comment: не понял ваш комментарий :-)

Comment: @Grundy, актуальная версия сафари - 9. Последняя версия под винду - 5, которая старше 12й оперы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну так в чем мой комментарий ошибочен? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы добавил, и возможно человек имел в виду, что есть отличия в Mac и Windows версиях. Это касается не только Safari, но бывает насущная проблема, что Safari не поддерживает некоторые технологии или стили воспринимаются по-другому.

Например, когда я столкнулся с проблемой работы с html5 видео, тех. поддержка Apple, утрирую, но ответила, что извините, браузер в данный момент не поддерживает функционал, после этого приходится использовать сторонние плагины или надстройки.

Есть специальные сервисы, в большинстве своем триальные и платные:

1. https://saucelabs.com/
2. https://browserstack.com/
3. https://crossbrowsertesting.com/

Они позволяют эмулировать работу браузера на разных платформах и версиях браузеров. Они в полной мере позволяют понять что код рабочий, стили не сползают. А вот если после этого проблема не уходит, это уже может быть связанно с локальными настройками компьютера, как вашими так и клиента, например из-за плагина в Chrome объект может отображаться с отличиями.

Answer (score 1):

Последняя версия сафари под windows 5.1. С оф сайта она убрана, можно легко найти в сети. В общем только так. Ну или ставить виртуальную машину + мак ос на нее.
Политика apple очень плохая в плане разработчиков, все инструменты разработчика под их продукты доступны только на их продуктах. 
Проблема не так остро стоит с десктопными версиями, а вот тестирование на мобильных устройствах apple это да, беда.

Answer (score 0):

практически всегда webkit на safari отображается так же как и на хроме. Просто нужно не забывать выставлять префиксы.